# Как переопределить bootstrap файл carousel.js в Yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-bootstrap

Возникла необходимость переопределить файл карусели **carousel.js** от **bootstrap**.
Содержимое **BootstrapAsset**

Код: Выделить всё

```
public $sourcePath = '@bower/bootstrap/dist';
    public $css = [
        'css/bootstrap.css',
    ];
```

Как видно `BootstrapAsset` ссылается на `@bower/bootstrap/dist`, а там в файле `bootstrap.min.js` все в куче. А мне нужно переопределить только `carousel.js` в `@bower/bootstrap/js`.
Подскажите, как грамотно переопределить один файлик и указать на него ссылку в `BootstrapAsset`, чтобы не затрагивать остальные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В компоненте `AssetManager` имеется свойство [$bundles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$bundles-detail), с помощью которого можно [кастомизировать набор файлов](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles), входящих в `AssetBundle`.

Так, например, для [BootstrapPluginAsset](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/blob/2.0.6/BootstrapPluginAsset.php) вместо `js/bootstrap.js` можно указать путь к другой, собственной сборке плагинов Bootstrap (например, если Вы используете для этих целей [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) или [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)), или указать отдельные пути к файлам для каждого из используемых плагинов. При этом важно иметь в виду, что все пути к css- и js-файлам указываются относительно [$sourcePath](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html#$sourcePath-detail), поэтому если Ваши файлы лежат за пределами этой директории, то её также нужно будет изменить. Например, конфигурация компонента `assetManager` в файле `config/web.php` могла бы  выглядеть следующим образом:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                'sourcePath' => '@bower/path/to/custom/bootstrap',
                'js' => [
                    'custom-bootstrap.js'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    ...
]
```